# How to enable other (non-registered) editors to use the Google Apps Script attached to a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi fellow Stack Overflowers,

Yesterday I used Google Apps Script for the first time and I tried to hide certain rows given on user input. For me this works absolutely fine. Everybody else can access the sheet if they have the link to it and they are allowed to edit certain cells. Another user verified that he can access the Apps Script and as such that it actually is attached to the file, but the Apps Script does not seem to run for anyone else but me.
'

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Cooldown")
  {
    if (e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart != 5) return;
    else if(e.value != "TRUE")
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart + 1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B6').setValue(false);
    } 
    else SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showRows(e.range.rowStart + 1);
  }
  else if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Benodigde Priesters")
  {
    if (e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart != 2) return;
    else if(e.value != "TRUE")
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart + 1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart + 3);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3').setValue(false);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B5').setValue(false);
    } 
    else 
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showRows(e.range.rowStart + 1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showRows(e.range.rowStart + 3);
    }
    
  }  
}
```

As you might have noticed from the Apps Script, its intended purpose is to hide certain rows if a certain checkbox is unchecked and show the rows if it is checked. Rows 3 and 5 are hidden and B3 and B5 are reset to false if B2 is unchecked. Similarly, rows 3 and 5 are shown if B2 is checked.

[Picture of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBchx.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that users are "allowed to edit certain cells". That implies that the sheets are protected.

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs under the account of the user at the keyboard. If that user does not have the right to edit the columns that you are trying to hide, the function will throw an error when it tries to hide the columns. You can inspect the errors at [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions).

To make it work, rename the `onEdit(e)` function to something like `hideColumns(e)` and use an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run it. Installable triggers run under the account of the user who set up the trigger.

Comment: "You are saying that users are "allowed to edit certain cells". That implies that the sheets are protected."
That is correct and it seems that was part of the problem that users were not allowed to edit the entire row. I granted the permission to edit the rows now and registered users are now able to hide the rows with the script.

"The onEdit(e) function is a simple trigger that runs under the account of the user at the keyboard. (...)"

This implies that a user still needs an account to benefit this function. Is it possible to make it accessable to users without logging in?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).